# Is there a syntax error in this iCalendar event code?

Tags: syntax-error, icalendar

I have a 'Subscribed Calendar' on my iPhone which fetches calendar events in the iCalendar format from a URL. The calendar works fine except it does not show the following event, is there a reason why? All other events show fine. I'm thinking there's maybe a problem with the way the event is formatted/syntax but I can't seem to find anything that may be causing it.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Meet with tenant DESCRIPTION:Notes: Meter readings\, SoC images\, post box key\, finalise Let Procedure.\nLocation: Apartment X X Woodland Road\, Bebington\, Wirral\, CHXX XXX\nEmployee: Michael Le Brocq\nStatus: Confirmed\nOriginally Arranged: 07/09/16 12:18:43 by Lucy Christian\nLast Updated: 12/09/16 15:57:05 by Michael Le Brocq\n UID:2432 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160914T160000 DTEND:20160914T151500 LAST-MODIFIED:20160912T155705 LOCATION:Apartment 5 20 Woodland Road\, Bebington\, Wirral\, CH42 4NT END:VEVENT
```

Code used to generate calendar events;

```
<?php

require_once('../inc/app_top_cron.php');

if (!empty($_GET)) {

// define and escape each GET as a variable

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

if (!empty($value)) {

${$key} = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, PrepareInput($value));

}
}
}

// company details
$company_details_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT company_id, company_trading_name FROM company WHERE company_token = '" . $company . "' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$company_details = mysqli_fetch_array( $company_details_query );

// the iCal date format. Note the Z on the end indicates a UTC timestamp.
define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis');

// max line length is 75 chars. New line is \\r\n

$output = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Property Software//Calendar//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:" . $company_details['company_trading_name'] . " Calendar" . "
\r\n";

$sql = "SELECT ce.*, ces.calendar_event_status_name
FROM calendar_event ce
INNER JOIN calendar_event_status ces
on ce.calendar_event_status = ces.calendar_event_status_id
WHERE ce.calendar_event_company_id = '" . $company_details['company_id'] . "'";

$calendar_event_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $calendar_event_query )) {

$calendar_event_subject = str_replace(",","\,", $row['calendar_event_subject']);

$calendar_event_description = str_replace(",","\,", $row['calendar_event_description']);
$calendar_event_description = str_replace("\r\n","\\n", $calendar_event_description);

$calendar_event_location = str_replace(",","\,", $row['calendar_event_location']);

// loop through events
 $output .=
"BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:" . $calendar_event_subject . "
DESCRIPTION:" . $calendar_event_description . "
UID:" . $row["calendar_event_id"] . "
STATUS:" . $row["calendar_event_status_name"] . "
DTSTART:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($row["calendar_event_start"])) . "
DTEND:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($row["calendar_event_end"])) . "
LAST-MODIFIED:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($row["calendar_event_date_updated"])) . "
LOCATION:" . $calendar_event_location . "
END:VEVENT
";
}

// close calendar
$output .= "END:VCALENDAR";

echo $output;

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: There's no line breaks, so it's impossible for a parser to know where one field ends and the next one starts. Maybe someone is booking a meeting to calk about ical formats, and "LOCATION:" is part of the invitation text, not the location tag for where the meeting will be held.

Comment: Are the \n tags not the line breaks?

Comment: AH. I see some now, after scrolling over a mile. but if they were actual line breaks, then they should cut/paste as a multiline text block. Since they're a literal ``\`` and `n` in there, probably you didn't build the text properly in the first place.

Comment: Apologies, I wanted to post the output exactly as it was output

Comment: well, show the code that you're using the generate this, especially any of the code that'd be outputting what should be a linebreak.

Comment: don't do multiline string building. use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) instead. especially since doing multi-line string building like that embeds the line breaks your editor is using, which may NOT be the line breaks wanted by the receiving/remote system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$calendar_event_description = str_replace("\r\n","\\n", $calendar_event_description);
```

You're taking `\r\n` (carriage return + newline) and turning them into a literal `\` character, followed by an `n`. That's not a new line (one byte/character), it's TWO bytes/characters, and has no special meaning to anything.

And as per my comments above, don't do multiline string building/concatenating. it makes for hard-to-read and hard-to-follow debugging. Use a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) instead:

```
$output = <<<EOL
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY: {$calendar_event_subject}
DESCRIPTION: {$calendar_event_description}
UID: {$row["calendar_event_id"]}
etc...
EOL;
```

Note the lack of any `"` or `.` - making for a much more compact and easy-to-follow code block. If you need to change the line breaks afterwards, because your system uses something different than what your code editor is embedding, you can do that with a simple str_replace() after finishing building the string.

Comment: Thanks Marc, how do I fix this?

Comment: if you're just trying to turn \r\n into \n, then just have `"\n"` as the replacement string. you've got two backslashes, so the first one escapes the second one, and since it's escaped, it's no longer an escape backslash, it's a literal backslash character.

Answer (score 0):

The icalendar standard requires \r\n line breaks between lines. You can validate the icalendar output using the validator at http://icalendar.org/validator.html